# Polynomial of degree $n-1$ fitted to the first $n$ primes.

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, prime-numbers

I called $f_n(x)$ the polynomial (of degree $n-1$) that produces the first $n$ primes, so I proceeded to study it but i found this https://oeis.org/A082594.

So someone has already studied this, but I'm not finding links or papers where I can read more about.

Does anyone know any place where they have this content?  Or can you at least tell me if what I found is right?

I think that
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i(-1)^i, a_i \in \mathbb N$$

Comment: The OEIS is pretty good at including links and references. If there's nothing useful there, it's a strong sign that no one has found much of interest to say about these polynomials.